# Trouble eliminating padding

Tags: html, css, styles, padding

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to lower/remove the padding in my header box. I've attached the relevant html and css code, and taken a screenshot of what I'm working on. I'm trying to lower the padding between the top and title, title and navBar, and navBar and bottom. If anyone's willing to look through the the code, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

[image]

**HTML code**

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS code**

```
#details {
font-size:16px;
font-family: Herculanum, "Gill Sans", Optima, Tahoma, sans-serif;
color:#A36D6A;
padding:0px;
}
#titleName {
font-size:30px;
font-family: Chalkduster, "Gill Sans", Optima, Tahoma, sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
color:#A32F2B;
}   
#headerDesign {
background-color: #2A4557;
margin:0px;
border:5px outset #fff;
text-align:center;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:0px;
font-family: Chalkduster, "Gill Sans", Optima, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
nav ul ul {
display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
}

nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15); 
padding: 0px 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
list-style: none;
position:relative;
display:inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
content:""; 
clear:both; 
display:block;
}
nav ul li {
float:left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background:#4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
nav ul li:hover a {
color:#fff;
}
nav ul li a {
display:block;
padding:10px 40px;
color:#757575;
text-decoration:none; 
}
nav ul ul {
background:#5f6975;
border-radius:0px;
padding:0px;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float:none;
    border-top:1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position:relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    color:#fff;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background:#4b545f;
}
nav ul ul ul {
position:absolute; 
left:100%; 
top:0;
}
```

Comment: doesn't `ul { margin:0 }`work? You didn't provide code for title so I can't answer that part but `h1{margin:0}` should work if its `h1`

Answer (score 0):

[Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), my friend.

There's a lot of things your browser will set by default, margins and padding being a great example. This is why if you try and make a div with a 100% width, it will only go to about 95% width give or take.

Though Reset is a great tool, make sure you look through all the things it is resetting. There might be a few changes to your current code you'll have to make, but it's not usually anything insane.

[Normalize CSS](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is another good option.

Comment: reset sometimes brings many unwanted and undesirable changes. Using reset just to get rid of a little `margin` is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

`@NoahKoch` send this first... You must `Reset CSS`, Because Chrome and FireFox have default margins and paddings for tags. The most common problem after this is broken `padding & width`
It will repair this:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  zoom: 1;
}
```